# `stream` is undefined on `ontrack` event in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

In WebRTC peer communication, i am trying to implement `Unified Plan` where Transceivers can be used. In that when the `ontrack` is fired, the stream is passed as `undefined`. However I can accesss the track from `transceiver.receiver.track`.

-> The problem is that, for video I need the stream instead separate track(audio, video). How to convert this separate track to a single stream? Is it intended feature or whether I need to set something inorder fetch the stream itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `track` event has a `streams` (plural) argument. If you know there's one stream, use:

```js
pc.ontrack = event => video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
```

This is because Unified-plan is track-based, and a track may be associated with more than one stream, or no streams at all.

A remote track's stream associations come from the arguments to *addTrack* or *addTransceiver*:

```js
pc.addTrack(track, streamMyTrackIsIn, optional2ndStreamMyTrackIsIn);
```

Only tracks are sent. Remote streams get recreated with ids matching the streams passed in above.

The *RTCPeerConnection* automatically manages the streams in `event.streams` for you, in response to things like `transceiver.direction` changes or the misnomer *removeTrack*.

Or create your own remote streams to put your tracks in any way you please:

```js
pc.ontrack = event => video.srcObject = new MediaStream([event.track]);
```

Use the latter only if you want to manage stream associations manually, as it can get [complicated](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/rtcrtptransceiver-explored/).

Comment: Nice  explanation. Thank you.